# how to get old url when there is redirection in scrapy?

Tags: redirect, scrapy

scrapy  version : 0.20

Problem:

```
start_urls=[URL1,URL2,URL3]

def parse(self,response):
    //suppose URL2 is redirected to other URL
    //I need to get current start URL(before redirection)
```

I have tried with response.request.url but it is same as response.url

please help me out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you've got `RedirectMiddleware` enabled (it should be enabled by default), you can try:

```
original_url = response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])[0]
```

See https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/redirect.py#L35 for implementation details